# Continuity on Hilbert schemes of points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I want to calculate the Euler characteristic of $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{C})$. For the Euler characteristic I use the version with compact support. Here the definition I use for the Hilbert scheme is the set of ideals $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $\dim \mathbb{C}[x]/I=n$.

I use this definition and tried to stay a bit away from actual schemes, since those go a bit above my grasp for now.But because I use this simpler definition, I am not completely sure how the topology works, and thus what maps are continuous.

An ideal $I$ in $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{C})$ is completely determined by its roots, and therefore we get a bijective map $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{C})\to S^n\mathbb{C}$ that looks continuous to me, but I'm not sure.

Moreover you could also choose a unique monic polynomial for each ideal, and then get a map from $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ by sending the polynomial to its coefficients (and ignore the first coefficient, since we choose it to be $1$ always). This map is again bijective and also looks continuous to me, but again, I'm not sure.

Are these maps continuous? And moreover are they homeomorphisms and can I conclude that $\chi(\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{C}))=\chi(S^n \mathbb{C})=\chi(\mathbb{C}^n)=1$?

Comment: Well unfortunately I have not gotten an answer so far, I have however found this article: https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/92526. It seems to suggest that at least $S^n\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ are homeomorphic. Therefore I think that my claims are true.